# Java: passing variable one time but different values

Tags: java

I'm a Java newbie and I have this question.

Can I pass a variable to a method multiple times without creating a new object?

For example, if I have a variable x which is the user input, another variable called m and a method were: if x is "h" then m is "example1" else if x is "f" m is "example2".

If I write:

```
String x = Scanner.next();
```

And I create the object passing the x variable, when I write,

```
System.out.println(obj.m);
```

If the input was h It will print out "example1"

But if write down this after what i showed up:

```
x = Scanner.next();
System.out.println(obj.m);
```

Whatever character I write down the output will be "example 1"

If I type "f" the first time the output will be "example2"
But the second system.out.println() will print "example2" eventually if I typed "h" the second time

So is it possible to pass a variable only one time with a value that changes over time without creating a new object?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. We don't know what `obj` is. Post a MCVE.

Comment: can you show the logic of how "m" is assigned a value? most probably, you need to evaluate the `m` assignment everytime you change the value of `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then yes, you can pass a variable to a method multiple times without creating a new object. Let's say you create a class like this:

```
public class Test {
    public String m;
    
    public void testMethod(String x) {
        if ("h".equals(x)) {
            m = "example1";
        } else if ("f".equals(x)) {
            m = "example2";
        } else {
            m = "other";
        }
    }
}
```

If you created an object from this class in a main method and pass in different values of `x` as the argument for `testMethod()`, the value of `m` would change:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj = new Test();
        
        String x = "h";
        obj.testMethod(x);
        System.out.println(obj.m); // prints example1
        
        x = "f";
        obj.testMethod(x);
        System.out.println(obj.m); // prints example2
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of x.equals("h") I always use "h".equals(x), because it works even if x is null. No NullPointerException.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But would a "Setter" method do tthe trick as well?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, I have added a solution that will create the object you mentioned one time and call the method inside it repeatedly as you enter values. This might help you

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ClassOfYourObject object = new ClassOfYourObject();
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter letter : ");
            String x = scanner.next();
            object.yourMethodToPrint(x);
        }
    }
}

class ClassOfYourObject {
    void yourMethodToPrint(String value) {
        if (value.equals("h")) {
            System.out.println("example1");
        } else if (value.equals("f")) {
            System.out.println("example2");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid letter");
        }
    }
}
```